# Regular expression ending with the first of two options

Tags: ruby, regex

In Ruby, I'm trying to extract from text a string that starts with "who" and ends with the **first** of either a ")" or "when" (but doesn't include the ")" or the "when").

I've tried the following:

```
who.*(?=when\b|\))
```

which fails the case where it finds both a "when" and a ")".

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your `.*` part non-greedy.

Try this regex :

```
who.*?(?=when\b|\))
```

Answer (score 0):

`(who.*?)(when|\))`

That should do it I think. $1 will be your string.